# window.getSelection() doesn't work properly on Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, cross-browser

I am facing a compatibility issue with firefox and window.getSelection() to get the selected textarea id from a list of textareas.

I am working on something like adding specific tags to a piece of text: click on a textarea then click on insert tags button.

I am using window.getSelection().focusNode.firstElementChild.id to get the active textarea and then update its content. It works perfectly for Chrome, however I got this error on Firefox: window.getSelection().focusNode is null

Can anyone help me to figure out what might be causing this or if there is a work around?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same problem regarding Firefox + getSelection().focusNode.
I've ended up getting rid of selection at all and used pointer events instead.